# Can keyboard shortcuts be disabled globally (not individually) in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, google-chrome-extensions

I'm really tired of my wayward fingers doing things I didn't intend and wish all applications had a convenient way to disable keyboard shortcuts globally. Does that feature exist in Chrome?  When I try to click on the "Disable keyboard shortcuts" radio button nothing happens, as if the radio button is disabled.  Conventionally (old-school) an on/off toggle should be represented by a checkbox but I think the single radio button has encroached on checkbox territory in recent years. Perhaps it's not even a radio button and just looks like one?

[image: Disable keyboard shortcuts]